# How to disable antialiasing for JavaFX Textures

Tags: java, 3d, textures, javafx-8, antialiasing

The title says it. What I want to avoid is this:

[image: blur]

As you can see, the floor (which is a TriangleMesh, with a texture) is blurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to use techniques like [mip-mapping and anisotropic filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anisotropic_filtering), neither of which are controllable via the JavaFX 8 3D API as far as I know.  Likely, internally the JavaFX implementation will use some degree of anisotropic filtering which is not configurable via public API.  The [diffuseMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html#diffuseMapProperty) used in a PhongMaterial only provides for a single texture image, not a mip-mapped image, and though there are scene aliasing hints that can be applied, that [concept differs](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8102959) from texture filtering hints which would be more applicable to your situation.  Likely, to achieve the result you wish, you either need to use a different API than JavaFX or a higher quality texture.